# Changing displayed price based on visitor location?

Tags: paypal, web-applications, geolocation, pricing

I run an online web app which at the moment I charge for in GBP.  I'm expanding to the US and Europe and am looking for the best way to change the displayed price based on where the visitor is located.  Because I use PayPal, ideally it would be great if it took into account the fee PayPal charges for currency conversion, but if not it wouldn't be the end of the world.

What would be the best way to do this do you think?

Comment: What software is the web app written in?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "Web App"?

Answer (score 1):

Using geolocation should do the trick?

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation

if client doesn't allow it , let them choose themselves, like they would choose a currency.
Also, think about it if it is worth charging your clients.

there are some discussions online about charing your clients for those fees or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can add multi-currencies feature into your website, after all it won't be that difficult. By having the customer's IP address, you shall be able to get the exchange rate in return.